# FB4Linux―debugger disconnects after a while

Tags: eclipse, actionscript-3, debugging, flash-builder

I am running ubuntu 12.04 64 bit, I have set up [FB4Linux (FlashBuilder for Linux)](http://code.google.com/p/fb4linux/) and installed the »flash-installer« installer plugin via »apt-get«. I downloaded the latest version of the [plugin-debugger from adobe](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) and followed the install instructions from the included README.txt file. Running eclipse (Version: 3.7.2, Build id: I20110613-1736), creating a new as3 project works, build works, everything fine, I can start the debugger and step through the code **BUT** after a while the debugger just disconnects and stops. No error, no crashes, debug session just over.

Any Ideas?

[.log](http://pastebin.com/7UfBEWRG)

#### about:plugins:

Flash - Version: 11.2 r202
Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202

Comment: is there **debugger** disconnected after some fix amount of time or at some Specific action?

Comment: feels like a fixed amount of time... -- definitively a fixed amount of time

Comment: interesting to know ? so can u add some error log? only and only this **error log** will help you and me to know what are the problem...

Comment: sure, no problem if you tell me where I can find a log...

Comment: in Project directory .metadata/.log is the error log file.. and also give me your flash player version.. when  i search about your error at some site i see, some flash player have this bug so provide your flash player version?

Comment: Does the debugger get disconnected only when you are stopped on a breakpoint? This happens in other OS/browsers, as the browser thinks the "script" (SWF) has stopped executing and terminates it. I recall this happening in Firefox, and that there was a Firefox preference you could change to alleivate the problem.

Comment: the debugger disconnects after a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

I think , this is happenning more fequently due the enhanced breakpoint listener support in eclipse.When a breakpoint is removed, it is trying to notify its "breakpoint specific" listeners, which were stored in the breakpoint. Of course, this will not work since the underlying marker has been deleted. but things will happen after removing break point. so one way to resolve this problem is to try to un-select

`Window > Preferences > Java > Debug : Suspend execution on uncaught exceptions`

may this will help you!!

Comment: thank you so far, but unfortunately that did not play the trick.

Comment: un-select all suspend execution's check-box then put result here
its just a blunt arrow to the answer but sometime works.
its a tough question @philipp Lolz...

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this issue occurred as side effect after I applied the changes from the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280022/flex-sdkwhere-to-get-the-right-version-with-playerglobals-swc-for-flash-player) question. When I tried to set the compiler options to target version 11.2, which is actually installed on my system errors occurred because their were files missing in the sdk folder (which are the described changes) and I could only develop for version 11.1. Kind of wired but the update of the sdk made the debugger run stable.