# flex sdk―where to get the right version with playerglobals.swc for flash player 11.2

Tags: flash, flash-builder, flash-player-11

I am developing with FB4Linux on Ubuntu 12.04 and I have installed the latest, for linux available version of the flashplayer, namely 11.2. When I searched the adobe reference I found that the [MouseEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html) support middle and right click events since version 11.2. I have downloaded the latest flex sdk 4.6 from [adobe here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex-sdk-download.html) and this sdk contains the playerglobals.swc for version 11.1, where these events are not supported yet.

Is it possible to update this sdk so that flashplayer 11.2 is the target runtime, or is this only possible for windows and mac since the flex sdk is handed over to apache flex sdk, where I can only find downloads for windows and mac.

greetings!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to http://get2.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/ and select the player you want.  Replace it in the sdk folder under runtimes/player/11.2 (you'll need to make the 11.2 folder).

Load that sdk in Flash Builder and see if you get the mouse support.

Comment: You might have to remove the 11.1 folder

Comment: Thank you so far, that did the trick! I also downloaded the playerglobals_11.5.swc created another folder in <sdk>/framework/libs/player/11.2/ and saved the playerglobal.swc there, so everything seems to work now...